# CSS Animating an underline when hover, stay when active

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I am learning to use React, and SASS together.

I have the follow SASS code

```
.option{
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  animation: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;

  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 51%;
    right: 51%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
    height: 2px;
    animation: left, right;
    transition-property: left, right;
    animation: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    animation: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  }

  &:hover:before, &:hover:focus:before, &hover:active:before{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

}

What I am trying to do is when the text is hovered over it underlines it with the animation, Then when you select the option, the underline stays instead of transitioning out.

I cant seem to figure it out.

Im just doing this on a basic React page.

```
<div className="options">
      <Link className="option" to="/">
        Home
      </Link>
      <Link className="option" to="/test1">
        Test1
      </Link>
      <Link className="option" to="/test2">
        Test2
      </Link>
    </div>
```

Comment: make each state alone, you are combing hover and active but you need to keep active alone

Comment: ok, thank you! that was an easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Temani-Afif it was just eluding me.

separating worked

```
&:active:before{
        left:0;
        right:0;
      }

      &:focus:before{
        left:0;
        right:0;
      }


      &:hover:before{
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
```